# increase the height of a text field in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i need to increase height of this  input field in woo commerce word press plugin . how can i do it with CSS...  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu6uT.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a url to the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.woocommerce-checkout form textarea#order_comments {
    height: 12em; // Set your height
}
```